# Firebase authentication error: Undefined name 'auth'

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to acces my firestore databse, by using the UID of each user, like so:

```
return new StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return new Text("Loading");
      }
      var userDocument = snapshot.data;
```

And for getting the UID:

```
final FirebaseUser user = auth.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
  final userid = user.uid;
});
```

This but I keep getting the error

```
Undefined name 'auth'.
```

Comment: Did you initialize the `auth` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `FirebaseAuth` in flutter, you must get a reference to such instance. Add this line at the top of your widget/file whenever you need to use Firebase Authentication:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

Now you can use stuff like `auth.currentUser().then(...)` like you are doing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined name 'FirebaseAuth', and not importing library firebase_auth